# Rails 4 + Apache error: End of script output before headers:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I deployed my Rails app with capistrano + passenger + ubuntu + apache. However, when I go to the homepage, the apache log shows:

`[Mon Jul 21 14:24:25.607537 2014] [core:error] [pid 14496:tid 139782018725632] [client 69.193.194.58:41506] End of script output before headers:`

How would I debug something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't have the environment secret configured set up in `secrets.yml`

Answer (score 1):

If you are in development you don't need to specify the secret key in the environment.

So just make sure that:

`RailsEnv development`

Is added to your virtualhost conguration

Comment: I thought that Passenger would assume development if no environment was given.  You just saved me a lot of time, thanks!